# Construct Dynamic Complex Where Clause in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause

I need to write a stored procedure that uses different where-clauses based on given input parameters. Specifically I need evaluate two date-time parameters, and based on these parameters, I need to construct different where-clauses. So far I am having problems making it work.

The stored procedures takes start-date and end-date parameters as given by users, and use these two parameters to find records that have their start-date and end-date overlapping these user-input parameters.

Below is the pseudo-code of the stored procedure I want to create:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_MyReport @organisation nvarchar(255) = NULL, @start_date nvarchar(255) = NULL, @end_date nvarchar(255) = NULL
AS

    DECLARE @dateTimeOverlapWhereClause nvarchar(1000)

    -- Construct the appropriate where-condition based on the user input
    if @start_date is not null and @end_date is not null
        @dateTimeOverlapWhereClause = (cast(start_date as datetime) <= prj.PlanEnd) and (cast(end_date as datetime) >= prj.PlanStart)
    else if @start_date is not null and @end_date is null
        @dateTimeOverlapWhereClause = (prj.PlanStart >= cast(@start_date as datetime))
    else if @start_date is null and @end_date is not null
        @dateTimeOverlapWhereClause = (prj.PlanEnd <= cast(@end_date as datetime))
    else -- both input dates are null so we use open-ended dates instead
        @dateTimeOverlapWhereClause = ((cast('1900-01-01' as datetime) <= prj.PlanEnd) and (cast('9999-12-31' as datetime) >= prj.PlanStart))

    -- This is the query that need to use the dynamic where condition
    select 
        prj.SrcGISID, 
        prj.PlanStart,
        prj.PlanEnd,
        prj.WorksClass, 
        prj.Description, 
        prj.JobStatus, 
        prj.Stage 
    from PROJECT prj 
    inner join ORGANISATION org on prj.OrgID = org.ID and org.OrganisationName = @organisation 
        and @dateTimeOverlapWhereClause

go
```

How do I make the @dateTimeOverlapWhereClause dynamically constructed? I have done some research but most of the answers are based on simple variables. SQL-injection is not so much a concern here as this stored procedure is used internally by organisation. I am using MS SQL Server 2012.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are major syntax errors in you procedure. What you need is dynamic sql

Comment: Yep, it's syntacally not right, as I said it's just pseudocode to express the idea...

Comment: Declare a `varchar(max)` variable and construct your query in the variable. The execute it using `EXECUTE` or `sp_executesql`

Comment: Thanks, that approach would work.